# Calculating Surface Area of Compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, databases

Is there any way to calculate the surface area of compounds such as **2,5-dimethylhexane** or **3-methylpentane**? If not, is there a database that has information on surface area of these compounds (**not polar surface area**). I'm doing an in-depth research between the correlation of surface area and boiling and melting point in branched chain isomers and really need to calculate the surface area of these branched chain isomers.

- if it's through a program, please specify if the program is free to use

Comment: [This article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097848592800474) looks promising. I will try to give an explanation once I have access to it.

Comment: I found the data at [https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj255Hwz-PSAhVE6SYKHXLgAnEQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.academia.edu%2F25385484%2FMolecular_surface_calculations_on_organic_compounds&usg=AFQjCNGS9L27LsHmJ1dfpBADGaTlwLrAAA&sig2=8FMJVht6UwAhhq8XcCQG0A.]

Comment: Cool, so it looks as though 3-methylpentane is included in the data set. You could presumably find the value for 2,5-dimethylhexane using the formula in their paper in reverse by experimentally measuring solubility. If this doesn't work [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=1SffUaPArh8C&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316&dq=msdot+algorithm+richards&source=bl&ots=wuxX6pNx2c&sig=864mceMX7h3bUtrzgS11cadKM18&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7e301uPSAhVINSYKHQQ5B0EQ6AEIHDAD#v=onepage&q=msdot%20algorithm%20richards&f=false) has more info on MSDOT.